# cat only writes to file evert 4.1kb

Tags: linux, awk, serial-port, cat

I'm using a script to write serial data to file however data is only written to file every 4.1kb. I would like every line that comes in to be written to file immediately. Is there any way to achieve this?

Script:
cat < /dev/ttyUSB0 | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S"), $0; }' > /path/log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stdbuf -oL` sets the output buffering of awk to per-line buffering:

`stdbuf -oL awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S"), $0; }' /dev/ttyUSB0 > /path/log`